# How to get the nearest similar color from dictionary of colors

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote a program to identify a color from file and prints the name of given colors, from which color of file has the highest similarity with. I used HSV to get range of color and compare HSV to this range to get the most similar color. I tried to iterate through the dictionary of colors to compare them to HSV of file I pass. However, it doesn't work and show any errors.

```
from pickletools import uint8
import cv2
from matplotlib import image
import numpy as np
#HSV Hue - color, Saturation - color density, Value - brightness of color. 
#use lower and upper value of a color to define range where picture will fit.
#opencv's HSV values are H(0-179)S(0-255)V(0-255)

img = cv2.imread('purple.jpg', cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
#colors 
color_list= {
    "white":([0,0,50],[0,0,255]),
    "black":([0,0,0],[0,0,49]),
    "red":([0,0,225],[127,0,255]),
    "green":([40,40,40],[70,255,255]),
    "yellow":([23,41,223],[40,150,255]),
    "blue":([78,158,124],[138,255,255])
}

#get image 
img = cv2.imread('purple.jpg')
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

for color_name, (lower, upper) in color_list.items():
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype = np.uint8)
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype = np.uint8)

    mask = cv2.inRange(img,lower,upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask = mask)

    if mask.any():
        print(f"{color_name} :{mask.sum}")
```

Comment: You are reading the image wrong. `cv2.imread` does not take `cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV` as a flag. Though the code doesn't throw an error, since it is interpreted as an integer. Its best to use `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` if the image is `.png`. But since you are reading a `.jpg` file you can skip it.

Comment: I fixed this line but it till doesn't work and show any errors

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. But instead of summing the pixels in `mask`, you need to find the number of white pixels for each color range

Here is a simple approach.

- For every color in the dictionary, obtain the `mask`
- The `mask` is a binary image (black and white image) with value of either `0` (black) and `255` (white). The white pixel means it contains the color within the specified range.
- For each color range, count the number of white pixels present in `mask`. The image has the corresponding color if its range has the most number of white pixels.

**Additional Code:**

```
final_color = None
final_count = None

for color_name, (lower, upper) in color_list.items():
  mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, tuple(lower), tuple(upper))

  # count non-zero pixels in mask
  count=np.count_nonzero(mask)
  
  if count > 0:
    final_count = count
    final_color = color_name
    

print("Nearest Color is {}".format(final_color))
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to call the `cv2.cvtColor()` method, like so:

```
import cv2

img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('purple.jpg'), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Comment: that's **not the problem**. OP does not indicate that this failed, and before using this value of `img`, OP reassigns it to the result of a correct imread call. if you're gonna post answers to a lot of questions, please take a moment to consider whether you've grasped the issue and your answer addresses the issue.